# Display win and loss for a little game

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am trying to make each player display "Each Players Wins and loose at every count, so they can see the ones they won and lost

some thing like:

Player A

Games: Status of Game
1  :     Win

2  :     Win

3  :    Win

4  :     Lost

5  :     Lost

6  :     Win

Player B

Games:    Status
1 :       Lost

2   :     Lost

3   :     Lost

4    :    Win

5    :    Win

6    :     Lost

Please help me out with this

```
class Guess
{

   
    public int GuessedNumber { get; set; }
   
    List<int> PlayerA = new List<int>();
    List<int> PlayerB = new List<int>();
    int countA = 0;
    int countB = 0;
    int count = 0;

    public void  Guu()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        GuessedNumber = rand.Next(1,7);
    }

    


    public int input { get; set; }
    
    public void FirstDisplay(string Active_Player)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{Active_Player}: Guess the number that i am thinking about");
        input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        count++;
    }
    public void CompareNumbers(List<int> PlayerA, List<int> PlayerB, ref string Active_Player)
    {
        if (Active_Player == "A")
        {
            if (input == GuessedNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Correct, i was thinking of {GuessedNumber} my turn");
                PlayerA.Add(1);
                PlayerB.Add(0);
                countA++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Wrong, i was thinking of {GuessedNumber} try again");
                PlayerB.Add(1);
                PlayerA.Add(0);
                countB++;
            }
        }
        else if (Active_Player == "B")
        {
            if (input == GuessedNumber)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Correct, i was thinking of {GuessedNumber} try again");
                PlayerA.Add(0);
                PlayerB.Add(1);
                countB++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Wrong, i was thinking of {GuessedNumber} try again");
                PlayerB.Add(0);
                PlayerA.Add(1);
                countA++;
            }

        }

    }
    public void Display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is the result of the game");
        Console.WriteLine($"Number of Game Played is: {count++}");
        if (countA > countB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Winner: A");
        }
        else if (countA < countB)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Winner: B");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Draw");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Player A has {countA++} point");
        Console.WriteLine($"Player B has {countB++} point ");

       

       

    }
}


class Program
{



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> PlayerA = new List<int>();
        List<int> PlayerB = new List<int>();
      string  Active_Player = "A";
        int count = 0;
        Guess guess = new Guess();
        string choice;
        do
        {
            guess.Guu();
            guess.FirstDisplay(Active_Player);
            guess.CompareNumbers( PlayerA,  PlayerB, ref Active_Player);
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue, Yes or No?");
             choice = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

        }
        while(choice == "yes");
        guess.Display();

    }





}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `List<int> PlayerA` and `List<int> PlayerB` ?

```
Console.WriteLine("PlayerA Games Status");
for ( int i = 0; i < PlayerA.Count; ++i )
{
    Console.Write( $"{i}: " );
    if ( PlayerA[i] == 0) Console.WriteLine( "Loss" );
    else Console.WriteLine( "Win" );
}
```

Do the same for `PlayerB`.